# Wordpress Error: A TimThumb error has occured

Tags: php, wordpress

I've encountered an error after installing wordpress onto a new domain.
I've contacted the theme developer and have had no luck resolving the issue.

I receive the following error when i copy the image link:

> Warning: touch() [function.touch]: Utime failed: Permission denied in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/folioway/core/thumb.php on line 190
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/folioway/core/thumb.php:190) in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/folioway/core/thumb.php on line 413
> A TimThumb error has occured
>
> The following error(s) occured:
> Could note create the index.html file.
>
>
> Query String : src=/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/CoffeetabeBox-custom_web1.jpg&w=187&h=187&zc=1&q=90
> TimThumb version : 2.8.2

I have not modified anything else aside from some CSS.

The thumbnails do not appear on the pages, however, the images do appear in lightbox.

I have set the permissions to the cache folder to 777, but this has not resolved the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciates. Thanks.

Comment: That's not a TimThumb error, it's a permissions error on your server, which happens to occur inside a bit of TimThumb code. Look at what's happning at line 190 and figure out what dir/file is not readable by your WP code.

Comment: touch() used on a directory always returns FALSE and prints "Permission denied" on NTFS and FAT Filesystem in windows

Answer (score 19):

It happened to me too, and this is the second time!

If you don't have time to discover why, but you want to keep it working, just rename, or delete your /cache folder; then, create a brand new /cache folder, set permissions to 777, and it will work again.

Comment: 777 is never the answer, 777 is always the worst thing to do !

Answer (score 5):

I found that the cache folder this is referring to is the one within the same folder as timthumb.php - find that file and the related cache folder and give the cache folder 777 permissions.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on a linux based server,

first find the FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY from the config file by (ex. in linux server open the file in vi commond)

```
vi /system/web/esupu/wp-content/themes/gadgetry-parent/framework/timthumb/timthumb-config.php
```

it could be like

```
define('FILE_CACHE_DIRECTORY', '../../cache/');
```

SO we change the cache folder ownership to user "www-data" which is the default user for Apache web server which runs this php codes,

```
sudo chown -hR www-data:www-data /system/web/esupu/wp-content/themes/gadgetry-parent/cache/
```

also, now better check if folder can be writable too (chmod permissions to 777)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 777 as others have suggested, use 755 to the /cache folder.

Answer (score 1):

I just delete the cache folder and refresh the page where code was, it started working.
I think it is the problem of file permission.

Answer (score 0):

Headers already sent is usually a symptom of whitespace either at the beginning or the end of the file - check timthumb.php and make sure you have no blank lines or space either before the

The other possibility is that /wp-content/uploads/ is not writable by the web server, but I'd bank on the first one being the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to a php.ini file:

```
 display_errors = Off
 display_warnings = Off
 output_buffering = On
```

Answer (score 0):

TimThumb is a separate open source project that is used by many WP plugins.

If updating folder permissions doesn't work for you, another solution which worked for me was to update the plugin's TimThumb script with the most recent version. You can download it here:
**https://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php**

In my case this file was in wp-content/plugins/events-manager/includes/thumbnails

Comment: that link returned a 404 sorry, moved to GitHub it seems, link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

For others that have this issue when using the [FiatLux Wordpress Theme](http://www.wpexplorer.com/fiat-lux-fullscreen-image-video-wordpress-theme/), as I am here is the solution:

1. Open FTP like Filezilla
2. Navigate to yoursite/wp-content/themes/fiatlux/includes*
3. Delete the cache folder
4. Recreate the cache folder, with permission setting 755
5. Download the updated [timthumb.php file from GitHub](https://github.com/GabrielGil/TimThumb) and replace (I renamed the old one timthumb.old to test
6. If you use a Media server/ CDN, then be sure to add that site to the $ALLOWEDSITES array in TimThumb.php file

*If using another Wordpress theme, then find the TimThumb.php file and corresponding cache folder in that theme/ plugins folder in wp-content

Answer (score -1):

in

```
src=/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/CoffeetabeBox-custom_web1.jpg&w=187&h=187&zc=1&q=90
```

try put a '?' between .jpg and &w, so it will be like this

```
src=/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/CoffeetabeBox-custom_web1.jpg?&w=187&h=187&zc=1&q=90
```